# jsp project connection with other project

Tags: java, jsp

In Eclipse:
there is a maven jsp web project(jspP) running ok. In the java resources of this web project (folder: Java Resources --src --local.java.code). I create a java class (caller.java) where I create instances of classes from another project(outP).
the project outP is correctly imported in caller.java (import com.java.....) and obviously there are no errors.
When I create another main.java (with a main method) class inside the local.java.code and call the caller.java, it executes ok bringing results..
BUT:
when I create an instance of the caller.java inside a jsp page, I get an error:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/java.....
```

obviously the error is referencing the classes inside the outP.

Now, I understand this is a run-time error and it could be solved if I insert the jar file of the outP inside the lib folder of jspP (Correct???)..
But the question is: Since I am working oh the outP project, I need to "link" it somehow with the jspP... How do I do that "dynamic" linking?

Answer (score 0):

All the other classes you import from caller.java (from another project outP) should eventually be placed on the WEB-INF/lib

You can use eclipse or MAVEN to do that.